# Armadillo concurrent chained operations hang

Tags: c++, multithreading, armadillo

We have an urban legend regarding chained Armadillo operations having "issues". Here's a comment from a recent code change:

```cpp
        // calculate coefficients
        // Note: yes, we could write this more efficiently in one line of code.
        // e.g., a = (s.t() * s).i() * s.t() * p
        // However we have had exception issues with armadillo that seem to have been solved
        // by un-chaining blocks of code, which we will do here:
```

The code, as implemented was functionally equivalent to the chaining, due to the use of `auto`:

```cpp
        auto      st     = s.t();
        auto      sts    = st * s;
        auto      stsi   = sts.i();
        auto      stsist = stsi * st;
        arma::vec a      = stsist * p;
```

This works fine, in a single thread instance. However, when running multiple threads (each thread operating on its own instances, so there should be no concurrency), the final statement hangs.

The fix is to explicitly assign the intermediate steps to `arma::mat`:

```cpp
        arma::mat st     = s.t();
        arma::mat sts    = st * s;
        arma::mat stsi   = sts.i();
        arma::mat stsist = stsi * st;
        arma::vec a      = stsist * p;
```

Now, all threads run just fine.

What is going on that Armadillo can't do chained operations on different objects concurrently?

Comment: "Use of C++11 `auto` is **not recommended** with Armadillo objects and expressions." - from the [Armadillo FAQ](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html)

Comment: yes, noted. And why the fix is to un-auto. However, the same issue arises with chained operations, as the comment suggests. The question is why it is unstable. As a Matlab replacement, chained operations should be commonplace. Or it could just be me